# Http server with socket-io on node.js doens't running

Tags: javascript, node.js

My http server on node.js using socket-io isn't running. I used `npm install socket-io` and running server.

This is the server's code.

```
    var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
// Create a node-static server instance
var file = new(static.Server)();

// We use the http moduleÕs createServer function and
// rely on our instance of node-static to serve the files
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8181);

// Use socket.io JavaScript library for real-time web applications
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

// Let's start managing connections...
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

        // Handle 'message' messages
        socket.on('message', function (message) {
                log('S --> got message: ', message);
                // channel-only broadcast...
                socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
        });

        // Handle 'create or join' messages
        socket.on('create or join', function (room) {

                /*var namespace = '/';
                for (var numClients in io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[room]) {
                    console.log(numClients);
                }*/

                //var numClients = io.sockets.clients(room).length;

                var numClients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room]!=undefined ? Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room]).length:0;

                log('SERVER: CLIENTS ' + room + ' has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');

                log('S --> Room ' + room + ' has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');
                log('S --> Request to create or join room', room);

                // First client joining...
                if (numClients == 0){
                        socket.join(room);
                        socket.emit('created', room);
                } else if (numClients == 1) {
                // Second client joining...                 
                        io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
                        socket.join(room);
                        socket.emit('joined', room);
                        log('S: sent JOIN message');
                } else { // max two clients
                        socket.emit('full', room);
                }
        });

        function log(){
            var array = [">>> "];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                array.push(arguments[i]);
            }
            socket.emit('log', array);
        }
});
```

While this is client's code connecting to the socket:

```
   var room = getParameterByName('room_name'); 

alert ("room_name: "+room);

// Connect to signalling server
var socket = io.connect();

// Send 'Create or join' message to singnalling server
if (room !== '') {
  console.log('Create or join room', room);
  socket.emit('create or join', room);
}
```

With `netstat -a` comand I saw what the server's port is active.. but it doesn't send messages.

I've another question: how can server sends messages not in broadcast, but to specified peers connected? I mean: instead of

```
socket.on('message', function (message) {
            log('S --> got message: ', message);
            // channel-only broadcast...
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
    });
```

How could I do? Thanks!

Comment: What does `doesn't running` mean?  What specific errors do you observe?  What does the browser say in the console when you try to connect to your server?  What do you see in the server console? Questions like this need to include very specific observations and need to show that you did basic debugging already and explain what you found when doing that debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> I've another question: how can server sends messages not in broadcast,
>   but to specified peers connected?

The second part of your question is that you just do `socket.emit()` to send to a single socket like this to send back to the same socket that just sent you a message:

```
socket.on('message', function (message) {
     log('S --> got message: ', message);
     // channel-only broadcast...
     socket.emit('message', "got your message");
});
```

Or, if you have a socket id value for some other connected client, you can fetch that socket on the server like this:

```
io.sockets.connected[id].emit(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've a question for you: how can i attach a socket id to my socket client? Thanks!

Comment: @pier92 - Every socket.io socket already has `socket.id`.  It is created automatically by socket.io.

Comment: thanks again. Last question. I'm using this server for a WebRtc communication for an exam. This server is enabled for supporting at maximum 2 clients. If i would to delete this constraint, how could i do? I redirect you to my gitlab:  http://dev.conf.meetecho.com/AT-Projects/SAVA/tree/master/CompleteNodeServerWithDataChannelOReillyReview

Comment: socket.id return undefined for me. Using Firefox 47.0.1. What type returns socket.id?

Comment: @pier92 - Every socket.io socket has a `socket.id` property so I'm not sure what you're doing where you don't see it.